# PHP date to show 2 digits on pre-teen numbers

Tags: php

I have a php calendar which displays all of the dates perfectly on the page but I need the pre-teen dates to display as a 2 digit number ( 01, 02, 03, etc ) but they are not showing up like that - How can I do this as it's important for the end link, i.e. href="events.php?date=20131201" instead of href="events.php?date=2013121".

Here is my complete code if this will help:

```
<?php
            $currDay = date("j");
            $today = date("d"); // Current day
            $month = date("m"); // Current month
            $displaymonth = date("F");
            $year = date("Y"); // Current year
            $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year); // Days in current month

            $lastmonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year)); // Days in previous month

            $start = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); // Starting day of current month
            $finish = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$days,$year)); // Finishing day of  current month
            $laststart = $start - 1; // Days of previous month in calander

            $counter = 1;
            $nextMonthCounter = 1;

            echo '

                <div class="calendarHeader"><strong>'.$displaymonth.' '.$year.'</strong></div>
                <div class="calendarDates">
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>M</b></div>
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>T</b></div>
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>W</b></div>
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>T</b></div>
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>F</b></div>
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>S</b></div>
                    <div class="calendarCell"><b>S</b></div>

                    <div class="clearLeft"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="calendar">
                ';

                if($start > 5){ $rows = 6; }else {$rows = 5; }

                for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
                    for($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++){             

                        if((int)$currDay > (int)$date) {
                           $class  ='calendarBlank';
                        }

                        if(($counter - $start) < 0){
                            $date = (($lastmonth - $laststart) + $counter);
                            $class = 'calendarBlank';
                        }else if(($counter - $start) >= $days){
                            $date = ($nextMonthCounter);
                            $nextMonthCounter++;

                            $class = 'calendarBlank';

                        }else if($counter <= $today){
                            $date = ($counter - $start + 1);
                            $class = 'calendarBlank';
                        }else{
                            $date = ($counter - $start + 1);
                            if($today == $counter - $start + 1){
                                $class = 'calendarToday';
                            }
                        }                               

                        echo '<a href="events.php?type='.$type.'&from='.$year,$month,$date.'&var='.$var.'" target="_parent"><div class="calendarCell '.$class.'">'.$date.'</div></a>';

                        $counter++;
                        $class = '';
                    }
                }

                echo '
                <div class="clearLeft"></div>
                </div>
            ';
            ?>
```

Comment: Look into `sprintf()`

Comment: The "teen" numbers, by the way, are 13-19. They don't include ten, eleven or twelve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str_pad()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) (assuming I am reading your code correctly and `$date` is the variable representing the days portion of your date)

```
$date = str_pad($date , 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

You can also use [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$date = sprintf("%02d", $date );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = sprintf("%02d", $date);   // e.g., 05

$date = sprintf("%4d%02d%02d", $year, $month, $day);  // e.g., 20130704
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'&from='.$year,$month,$date` use

```
'&from='.sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $year, $month, $date)
```

or

```
'&from='.$year.str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad($date, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

or

```
'&from='.date("Ymd", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date,$year))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of date manipulation, I'd strongly suggest using the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$today = new DateTime("2013-01-01");
echo $today->format("Ymd");
// 20130101
```